# How to export a 3D plot using tikzplotlib and import it in LaTeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, tikz

Consider following code (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275178/pyplot-how-to-increase-the-resolution-of-plot-surface-and-how-to-remove-the-lin)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import tikzplotlib

r=np.linspace(0,1,11)
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,11)
R,Theta=np.meshgrid(r,theta)
X,Y=R*np.cos(Theta),R*np.sin(Theta)
Z=R*np.sin(Theta)*np.cos(Theta)

fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
ax=fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.inferno,linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('test here')
plt.show()

tikzplotlib.save("testfigure.tex")
```

which gives following figure :

[image]

When I import the file `testfigure.tex` in a LaTeX file, after having replaced

```
\begin{axis}[
hide x axis,
hide y axis,
```

by

```
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
width=10cm,
```

I obtain this result :

[image]

What can I do, in order to have the axis as in the Python figure? Or is this simply not possible with `tikzplotlib`?

Answer (score 1):

Github Readme of tikzplotlib states 3D plots are not supported (2021).

[Tikzplotlib - Github](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib)